# How to add or update an associated attribute while creating a new user at sign up with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, many-to-many, has-many-through

I'm having three models:

- Users can have several Interests and several Places.
- Users can share same Interests, but the Interests table should not
  contain duplicates and a user should not have duplicates Interests
  too.
- A Place can have several Users and can have Interests through its
  Users.

I would like to be able to create a user at sign up and add its interests and places as associated attributes.

Users can share same interests, so if it an interest already exist at sign up, I would like to simply add a link for the new user.

What I could get until now is to add interests while signing up with the user, but if an interest already exist, than I get an error and the user is not registered at all.
This is because I have a put an index on the interests and added a uniquesness validation on interests. Without it it was adding duplicate interests in the interests table.

Here are the classes I use:

`models/user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :confirmable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
  has_and_belongs_to_many :places

  validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_associated :interests

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :interests

  def interests_list=value
    value.split(',').each do |interest|
      self.interests.build(:name => interest).save
    end
  end

  def interests_list
    self.interests.join(',')
  end
end
```

`models/place.rb`

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :interests, through: :users
end
```

`models/interest.rb`

```
class Interest < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

The form for Devise:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <h3>Add interests</h3>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :interests %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :interests_list %>
  </div>

  <% if !user_signed_in? %>
    <h3>Sign up</h3>

      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

I'm using Rails 5.1.4 and Devise 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Shiko answer's, I tried up things and finally ended up with the following:

```
  def interests_list=value
    current_interest = value.split(',').collect{|interest| interest.strip.downcase}.uniq
    current_interest.each do |interest|
      self.interests << Interest.find_or_create_by(name: interest)
    end
  end
```

With this I'm able to attribute several times the same interest to several people without having duplicates in the Interest table.
Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a quick check for interests before saving them or use `.first_or_create` to create interest if it doesn't exist, like below:

```
 def interests_list=value
    current_interest = value.split(',')
    unique_interest = current_interest - Interest.where(name: current_interest).pluck(:name)
    unique_interest.each do |interest|
      self.interests.build(:name => interest).save
    end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the first option and I could be able to create a user even if it had interests which already exist. However, he was created without any interests. When he had some new interests and some which already exist, then the new one is attribute to him, but not the old one.
The second option didn't work because I have this error "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved".

Comment: @KillianKemps I will remove the 2nd to avoid confusion for others